# What stock graphics are available for promoting a site?

Tags: discussion, images, design, site-promotion

I'd like to use graphics that have already been developed for my SE site in promotional materials. So far, I've found a small icon at https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/judaism/img/icon-48.png , but I'm wondering what else exists, including larger versions of that icon or anything else. I can't browse that /img directory, so I'm wondering if someone who can could post a catalog of the standard contents of such directories.

Comment: A larger version would be the Apple touch icon Tim linked below. Feel free to use the header graphic too. Once the site graduates from the Beta phase it will get a custom design so it will have a stronger identity.

Comment: Thanks, @Jin. Could you please point me to where I can get the header graphic? My usual right-click, "View image" technique doesn't work on that, and it's not readily apparent to this non-CSS-expert from the page source either. I'm really looking forward to working with you on a custom design when we get out of beta, especially after hearing your podcast episode. What we've gotta do now is the promotion that will help get us there!

Comment: the header graphic is here: http://cdn.sstatic.net/judaism/img/logo.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what additional images are available, but you can find a larger version of that image by substituting `apple-touch-icon` for the filename, e.g.:

[image: larger icon]

Be sure to adhere to the [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) where applicable.

Comment: There's also http://stackexchange.com/about/logos for generic SE logos.

Comment: Thanks for the link and for bringing up the trademark issue. It's not clear to me how those trademark rules apply to graphics for individual sites. @Jin?