# Where can I find image files of Stack Exchange sites' logos?

Tags: support, images, logo

I like to use Google Chrome's Speed Dial extension for my main bookmarks, which include a lot of SE sites. I can link to image files in Speed Dial to make its buttons look nicer.

Is there a specific standard link I can use to access the logos of SE sites?

Comment: Related: [What stock graphics are available for promoting a site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100718)

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32755/icons-for-stack-overflow-and-super-user-for-prism-windows-7-pinned

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [network sites information API request](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) includes the site logos in its response. The logos' current URL format seems to be `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/SITENAME/img/logo.png`, where `SITENAME` is one of `stackoverflow`, `apple`, `gamedev`, etc..

For favicons, the format is `https://example.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico` and `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/SITENAME/img/favicon.ico`

For convenience, here are all of the logos by site, excluding generic betas due to the character limit:

- [image] [Android Enthusiasts](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/android/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/androidmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Database Administrators](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/dba/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/dbameta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Drupal Answers](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/drupal/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/drupalmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Christianity](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/christianity/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/christianitymeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Arqade](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/gaming/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/gamingmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Cross Validated](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stats/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/statsmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Ask Ubuntu](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntumeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Ask Different](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/apple/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/applemeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Bicycles](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/bicycles/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/bicyclesmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Skeptics](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/skeptics/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/skepticsmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [SharePoint](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/sharepoint/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/sharepointmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Mi Yodeya](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/judaism/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/judaismmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Game Development](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/gamedev/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/gamedevmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Personal Finance & Money](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/money/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/moneymeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [English Language & Usage](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/english/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/englishmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Server Fault](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/serverfault/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/serverfaultmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Stack Apps](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackapps/img/logo.png)
- [image] [Photography](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/photo/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/photometa/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Role-playing Games](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/rpg/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/rpgmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Software Engineering](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/softwareengineering/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/softwareengineeringmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Mathematica](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathematica/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathematicameta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Electrical Engineering](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/electronics/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/electronicsmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Seasoned Advice](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cooking/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cookingmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Mathematics](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/math/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Home Improvement](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/diy/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/diymeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Physics](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/physics/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/physicsmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Information Security](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/security/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/securitymeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Graphic Design](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/graphicdesign/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/graphicdesignmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [MathOverflow](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathoverflow/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathoverflowmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/scifi/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/scifimeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Geographic Information Systems](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/gis/img/logo-small.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/gismeta/img/logo-small.png))
- [image] [WordPress Development](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/wordpress/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/wordpressmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cstheory/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cstheorymeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Webmasters](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/webmasters/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/webmastersmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Web Applications](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/webapps/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/webappsmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Travel](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/travel/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/travelmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [The Workplace](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/workplace/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/workplacemeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Super User](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superusermeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Stack Overflow](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [TeX - LaTeX](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/tex/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/texmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [User Experience](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ux/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/uxmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Unix & Linux](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/unix/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/unixmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Ask Patents](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/patents/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/patentsmeta/img/logo.png))
- [image] [Stack Overflow em Português](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/img/logo.png) ([image] [meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/brmeta/img/logo.png))

Comment: What about favicons? Where can I find those?

Comment: @Ephraim `http://example.stackexchange/favicon.ico` and `http://cdn.sstatic.net/SITEDOMAN/img/favicon.ico`.

Comment: [icon-16](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cs/img/icon-16.png), [icon-32](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cs/img/icon-32.png), [icon-48](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cs/img/icon-48.png).

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange has a page for the major sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos).   Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Careers.

[image]

**158x158 px**

For every other site, you can find a full list of smaller icons on the [SE site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

[image]

**48x48 px**